# Implement a check-and-restart mechanism in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am New to AWS Serverless and I have a query. The data pull Lambdas are subject to time out on long-running pulls like I have 1ook records to fetch and sometimes Lambda times out at 50k for X reason. Is there a way I can implement a check-and-restart mechanism where in case if fails on 50K it restarts from what has last processed? or pull from beginning but instead of 100k now 80k  or 60k?

Comment: Change the retry count & timeout settings as needed for each use case. To allow enough time for a response to the API call, add time to the Lambda function timeout setting ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-console.html )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical problem: trying to use a Lambda for a *long running* process. By its nature serverless functions are more suited for short running processes (e.g. fetch user data from a database and return it). So by themselves they are not a good tool for this kind of job.

There are however ways to use Lambdas for *long running* processing requirements by changing the approach.

You did not give enough detail to provide you with a more detailed solution, but there are two common approaches:

1. [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/): Step Functions allow you to model "workflows" that can run up to a year. Those step functions are build from multiple "steps". A step can be running a Lambda, reading and writing to DynamoDB, SQS etc. Your first step could read from your datasource and then you could run multiple Lambda functions in parallel to process a subset of the overall dataset. This would reduce the amount of data a single Lambda invocation processes, thus avoiding timeouts.
2. Write a Lambda that reads items from your datasource and put them into one of the "queue" products of AWS (SNS, SQS). At the "other end" of those queues you can have a Lambda function that only processes a small subset of your items. This is repeated until all of the items are processed.

There are a lot of different AWS products to achieve similar things. Without more requirement details it is hard to give you a better answer.

But one thing I like to mention is, that more often than not working with AWS is about combining *several* AWS services rather than doing everything with a single service.